# How the upsell products handled in view page?

Tags: collection, magento2.2.2, up-sells

How magento 2 displayed only the in-stock upsell products in view page. How they handled and displayed

I wish to display upsell product collection in list page on each product.
I got the upsell product collection using below code and I got the upsell product collection (But it got both in-stock and out of stock products). I need to display only instock upsell products. So Please Provide me a solution to get in-stock upsell products

> $product->getUpSellProductCollection()

but while getting collection itself ,how do i add stock status filter then wish to get the upsell collection.

> I don't want foreach each item and check stock status

Comment: Add more details and provide more explanation. Add code and methods, you are trying

Comment: why you haven't put these details earlier while adding the question.learn how to put questions in stack

Answer (score 0):

**Handle Upsell Products**

- Open product in Edit mode in the admin page. Then under the Advance
  setting section, find Up-sell Section.

[image: upsell]

- Now you start to add Up-sell products to the product you open above in Edit mode.
- Tap Reset Filter in the upper-right corner to display all the available product to choose as Up-sell. Use Filter tool if it’s necessary.
- After you are done choosing, remember to Save.

**Displayed only the In Stock Upsell Products**

Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

Set Display Out of Stock Products to NO

[image: out of stock]